Is this how the bts things works for given code if return value optimization is not considered?
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class A{
    
    public:
    int data;
    A(int s){
       data=s; 
    }
    
    A(A &obj){
        data=obj.data;
        cout<<"Copy"<<endl;
    }
};


A getobject(){
    A obj(2);
    return obj;
}

int main(){
    
    
    A newobj = getobject();
    
    return 0;
}

My understanding is that first the temporary object is created to store the object returned by getobject() function and then the temporary object is copied in the newobj hence the copy constructor is called. If this is true then is it like at the time when we store the returned obj into temporary object there too copy mechanism is used if not then what?
note-Please ignore namespace and library.

"first the temporary object is created to store the object returned by getobject() function and then the temporary object is copied in the newobj hence the copy constructor is called" <-- conceptually maybe. But compilers these days wouldn't duplicate copying like that. You may be able to explore that by seeing the compiled code. Obviously use an absolutely minimal example for yourself

@Argyll so when we store the returned object in temporary one then is it copied or what? that's my question.

The answer is "maybe"  In case like this getobject would be allowed to construct A in place. That's why relying on side-effects of constructor is UB.


My understanding is that first the temporary object is created to store the object returned by getobject() function and then the temporary object is copied in the newobj hence the copy constructor is called. If this is true then is it like at the time when we store the returned obj into temporary object there too copy mechanism is used if not then what?

Since C++17 (which you have tagged) none of this is true. Fundamentally, there are only two A objects in your code: The object instantiated from the variable obj and the one instantiated from the variable newobj. No temporary object exists, even in principle.
getobject() is a prvalue expression which immediately initializes its result object, which is newobj, with the expression in the functions return value, i.e. newobj is copy-initialized from the expression obj, except that there is a special rule when the expression in the return statement simply names a local variable. In that case obj is considered to be a xvalue (i.e. a rvalue) instead of an lvalue as normal, so that a move constructor would be used instead of the copy constructor if it was possible. (The last sentence is technically only true since C++23, beforehand it was more complicated, but with the same outcome here.)
There is no return value optimization or copy elision going on anymore when returning from the function, although casually the C++17 rules are referred to as "mandatory copy elision". The only copy elision that is still possible is named return value optimization, which would identify the obj with the newobj object, so that all together only one object without any copies or moves exists.
